# Datastax java driver 4.5 tinkerpop dependecies

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Datastax java driver 4.5 has a lot of dependencies. 
Is tinkerpop required to use Datastax java driver to connect to a cassandra database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tinkerpop dependency is required only when you're working with DataStax Graph.  As [documentation states](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.5/manual/core/dse/graph/), you can exclude it:

> The driver has a non-optional dependency on that library, but if your application does not use graph at all, it is possible to exclude it to minimize the number of runtime dependencies (see the [Integration>Driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.5/manual/core/integration/#tinker-pop) dependencies section for more details).

and linked documentation shows driver declaration as:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
  <version>${driver.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
      <artifactId>gremlin-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
      <artifactId>tinkergraph-gremlin</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```